# Spring RestTemplate HTTPs service call org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have to test Rest service. When I am trying with postman or curl utility it is working fine. But when I execute it using Spring RestTemplate I am getting below error. Any idea what's wrong? I am using spring boot 1,5, Spring 4, SPring STS

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://uat.pci.api.testconsumer.com/digital/dpu/charges/bankverification/v1": Software caused connection abort: recv failed; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:673)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:414)
    at com.testconsumer.consumer.workflow.integration.service.BankVerificationService.verifyBankDetails(BankVerificationService.java:113)
    at com.testconsumer.consumer.workflow.integration.bankverification.BankVerificationTest.testBankVerification(BankVerificationTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.executeInternal(BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:99)
    at com.testconsumer.consumer.workflow.integration.config.RestResponseLogger.intercept(RestResponseLogger.java:26)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:86)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:70)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:659)
    ... 33 more
```

Code

```
@Bean
public SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectiontimeout);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readtimeout);

    return clientHttpRequestFactory;
}

@Bean(name = "bankSerivcerestTemplate")
RestTemplate bankSerivcerestTemplate(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory) {

    ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

    restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new RestResponseLogger());

    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            try {
                return super.hasError(response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Exception [" + e.getMessage() + "] occurred while trying to send the request", e);
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
            try {
                super.handleError(response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Exception [" + e.getMessage() + "] occurred while trying to send the request", e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    });

    return restTemplate;
}

public ResponseEntity<ObjectNode> verifyBankDetails(RestRequest request){

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    //Headers

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    //Params

    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(params, headers);

    ResponseEntity<ObjectNode> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, httpEntity, ObjectNode.class);
    JsonNode root = objectMapper.valueToTree(response.getBody());

    //Parse response

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when Server is waiting for the response from some other process e.g. client request has timed out at Server end.Server is complaining it's fine and the client has closed the TCP connection may be due to timeout or any RuntimeException at the client end.In your case, check if the endpoint has any issues with processing the request due to any exceptions or database issues.

You are receiving this error which means that the client is not responding :

- Check your logs to verify that for the request through the rest template the request headers are correctly present and that you are not missing any parameters.